# Convert Yen to Float in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string that looks like this: "¥3,250". I want to convert it into a float.

I already tried something like this:

```
    price = "¥3,250"
    price[0] = ""
    price.to_f
```

but ruby uses the comma (,) as a decimal seperator.

Comment: Float really isn't the best data type for currency, Fixnum or [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html) would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
price_as_float = price.scan(/\d|\./).join('').to_f
```

It should work even with, say `"¥3,250.4"`

All it does is extract digits and dots from the string and creates a string from it, then casting it to a float

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
   price = "¥3,250"
   price.gsub(/[,|¥]/,'').to_f   #=> 3250.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price = "¥3,250"
price.delete("¥,").to_f
```